# Using a loop to find greatest integer in array using Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, integer

I need to find the greatest integer in an array using a loop in Ruby

ex: numbers = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]

*note* I can't use the .max function. HAS TO BE A LOOP.

Comment: If you're going to post your homework, at least show us what you've tried so far, and where you got stuck.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a homework exercise, without any attempt to solve it.

Comment: `do`, `while` and `until` employ loops, but enumerator with blocks do not. If you do not mean to exclude the latter you may wish to strike the all-caps sentence. I presume the entire family of `max` methods is off-limits (`max_by, minmax, etc.)

Comment: How about `arr = numbers.uniq; (arr-arr.min(arr.size-1)).first #=> 60`?

Comment: @eugen, are those valid reasons for closing? Reference? Many times I see newbies (never veterans!) scolded for not showing their attempt at a solution. The plain fact is that newbies often have no idea where to start  to solve the problem. Should we force them to present gibberish?  So what if it's homework? We're here to teach, not to serve as instructors' aides.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - specifically point 3.

Comment: @eugen, the part dealing with homework states, "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." That's reasonable, as it does not necessarily demand code. (Have you ever worked on a problem for hours and not had any code to show for it?) I suggest that in these cases the OP be asked to respond to what I quoted above, rather than to "*show* us what you've done", which to me means "show us your code". Only if the OP refuses to do so should a vote to close be issued.

Answer (score 3):

Create another variable to store the current max, and then loop through the numbers.

```
max_num = 0
numbers.each { |n| max_num = n if n > max_num }
```

Comment: See the post by @Cappy  for a revised version of this  :)

Comment: You and @Cappy should both add `max_num` as a third line, to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 3):

I love using `inject` for something like this

```
numbers.inject(0){|acc,n| n > acc ? n : acc}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another one to use is the Enumerable [`reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce).

```
[-1000000, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100, 60, 80].reduce {|x,y| x > y ? x : y}
=> 100
```

Comment: `reduce` is preferred to `inject`, which @danielrsmith used in his earlier answer?

Comment: Both ``reduce`` and ``inject`` do the same things (reduce is an alias of inject), however according to [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#map-find-select-reduce-size) it is preferred to use reduce.

Comment: I realize that. I just don't see the point of your answer considering that it is a duplicate of an earlier answer.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to philip yoo's answer, but works for an array of negative numbers.

```
max_num = numbers.first 
numbers.each { |n| max_num = n if n > max_num }
```

Comment: Good catch! `max_num` should be set to first number in array rather than 0   :)

Comment: ...or to `-Float::INFINITY #=> -Infinity` (same as `-1.0/0`).

Answer (score 0):

This code is run on a `for` loop instead of  `.each`. From what your questioned asked, I thought you might need an actual loop constructor.

```
numbers = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
greatest_num = numbers.first
for n in numbers
    greatest_num = n if n > greatest_num
end
p greatest_num
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a loop, but you could use recursion.

```
numbers = [10, 20, 30, 40, 60, 50]

def biggest(arr)
  return arr.first if arr.size == 1
  cand = biggest(arr[1..-1])
  arr.first > cand ? arr.first : cand
end

biggest(numbers) #=> 60
```

Answer (score 0):

A more "newbie" way (since i am one :-)) Started the Ruby journey 2 weeks ago

```
numbers = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60] # your array
max_num = numbers[0] # Setting max_num to the first element of your array    
numbers.size.times{|x| if max_num < numbers[x] then max_num = numbers[x] end} # I use 
 #* the .size method to find how many elements are on your array and the .times method
 #* to iterate "size" "times" over your array.  In the block you have a simple comparison
puts max_num #displaying the result
```

So, a little bit more detail.... An array index always starts at 0. We never assign zero to our max_num variable because your array might contain negative numbers.

The numbers.size.times thingy... In Ruby we can use multiple methods on an object and in our example the object is the array numbers. So, numbers.size will return 6 (remember arrays start at 0. So from 0 to 5 equals 6 elements on your array) and then we use the .times method to loop 6 times the block.

Inside the block... .times method will pass to variable x the values from 0 to 5. So, all that remains is to do a simple comparison. If our max_num is less than our numbers array in x position (numbers[x]) then then make numbers[x] my new max_num (max_num = numbers[x]). The block will repeat it self 6.times :-)

The code works.. As for the explanation.. This is how I understand it... And since English is not my native language i ask the community to comment (good and bad) both the code and the explanation...